# Get the current position of the drag node

Tags: java, javafx, coordinates, mouse

This code allows the node to move while holding the mouse:

```
private double xc, yc;
private void makePortable(Node node){
    node.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
        xc = node.getTranslateX() - event.getSceneX();
        yc = node.getTranslateY() - event.getSceneY();
    });
    node.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
        node.setTranslateX(xc+event.getSceneX());
        node.setTranslateY(yc+event.getSceneY());
    });
}
```

This method is built into the singleton. It has a method to which the node is transferred, which is added in the Pane and is previously made portable.

```
public static final Word WORD = new Word();

private Pane input;
private Text text; 

private Word(){
}

public void init(Pane input){
    this.input = input;
}

public void addCanvas(Text text){
    this.text = text;
    makePortable(text);
    input.getChildren().add(text);
}

public void draw(){
    //And here I need to get his current coordinates
    action(text.get???X(), text.get???Y()); 
}
```

But now I need to get the coordinates of the offset node. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not resolved, but I found a workaround. If you need to put a knot on the `Canvas` and draw it, then you first need to take `Pane`(I advise `StackPane`) the `Canvas` and add the knot.

Next you need to take a screenshot `Node` and upload this screenshot to the `Canvas`. Code:

```
public void loadImage(Image image) {
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().drawImage(image,
            0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
}

public void action(){
    WritableImage wi = new WritableImage((int)canvas.getWidth(),
            (int)canvas.getHeight());
    pane.snapshot(null, wi);
    loadImage(wi);
}
```

And at the end of `Pane`, delete the incoming `Node`. Good luck! (: